# $g(n)$ upperbounds $f(n)$ but graph shows otherwise

Tags: algorithms, logarithms, asymptotics, graphing-functions, analysis-of-algorithms

Given we have the following functions:

$$f(n)=\log_{2}^{4}n$$
$$g(n)=2^{\sqrt{\log_{2}n}}$$

I've done the limit of f(n) over g(n), and found that g(n) is an upperbound of f(n) given the zero result:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log_{2}^{4}n}{2^{\sqrt{\log_{2}n}}}=0$$

This means that at a sufficiently large n, g(n) should be greater than f(n), but when I graph them together, no matter how big I set n, I cannot see a trend of g(n) eventually overcoming f(n).

Could this be because the value of n needs to be unimaginably large, that I cannot see it on a graph? If this is the case, is there still merit in stating that g(n) is the upperbound of f(n)?

Answer (score 1):

If you let $n=2^{x^2}$, then $f=x^8$ and $g=2^x$.

$$x^8=2^x \qquad \implies \qquad 8\log(x)=x \log(2)$$ which is much easier to visualize.

The exact solution is given in terms of Lambert function
$$x=-\frac{8 }{\log (2)}\,\,W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\log (2)}{8}\right)$$ which, numerically, is $43.5593$.

So, $n=1.5034\times 10^{571}$

Answer (score 0):

Pick $n = 2^K$ for some large $K$. Then
\begin{align}
f(n) 
&= [\log_2(n)]^4 \\
&= K^4\\
&= {2^{\log_2(K)}}^4 \\
&= 2^{4\log_2(K)} \\
\end{align}
while
\begin{align}
g(n) 
&= 2^\sqrt{\log_2 N} \\
&= 2^\sqrt{K}
\end{align}

So when $\sqrt{K}$ is larger than $4 \log_2{K}$, $g$ will be larger than $f$. Let's try $K = 100$:
$$
\sqrt{100} = 10\\
4 \log_2{100} \approx 4 \cdot 6.65 \approx 26
$$

Nope. Not quite big enough. The actual crossover seems to happen at about $K = 1900$, so let's try $K = 2000$. In that case we have
$$
\sqrt{2000} \approx 44.72...\\
4 \log_2{2000} \approx 43.86...
$$

How large is $N = 2^{2000}$? Well, $10 \approx 2^{3.32}$, so $N$ is about
$$
10^{\frac{2000}{3.32}} \approx 10^{602} 
$$
i.e., a 602-digit number. So I guess your conjecture about "because the value of $n$ needs to be unimaginably large, that I cannot see it on a graph?" is a reasonable one.

I like to keep in mind that there are something like $10^{51}$ elementary particles in the universe, so that if you are working on some algorithm, it's hard to imagine a practical instance in which $n$ is larger than this. On the other hand, if you're doing mathematical analysis and studying asymptotic behavior, numbers like this are perfectly reasonable.

Also, to backpedal a little bit on that $10^{51}$ thing

- you might have more than that many *moments* to consider in some algorithm that considers time-varying data
- knowing an upper bound for something can help the next person developing an algorithm know a little bit more about where to look, so even wild things like this can be useful

Comment: Isn't  $3.28\times 10^{80}$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment, Claude --- isn't *what* $3.28 \times 10^{80}$?

Comment: I think that this is the number of particules in our universe.  https://www.popularmechanics.com/space/a27259/how-many-particles-are-in-the-entire-universe/

Comment: Ah...my own reference comes from a book published in about 1960, combined with the possibly-faulty memory of a 13-year-old. :) Thanks for the update.